# Handling out of memory in a Native Android App

Tags: android, c++

I have a C++ Android app that periodically crashes on devices with only 768MB RAM because it runs out of memory. The application crashes in "malloc" or "dlmalloc_real" on these devices. Below I provided one of the possible stack traces reported by Google Play Console:

```
  #00  pc 00000000000225ac  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  #01  pc 00000000000130b1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
  #02  pc 00000000000132c5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  #03  pc 0000000000011ff9  /system/lib/libc.so
  #04  pc 0000000000021e60  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  #05  pc 0000000000012ae1  /system/lib/libc.so
  #06  pc 000000000000f205  /system/lib/libc.so
  #07  pc 000000000001010d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+604)
  #08  pc 000000000000dce7  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
  #09  pc 00000000000cf8d1  /system/lib/libGAL.so (gcoOS_AllocateMemory+8)
  #10  pc 00000000000cf943  /system/lib/libGAL.so (gcoOS_Allocate+46)
  #11  pc 0000000000029d65  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so (__eglMalloc+16)
  #12  pc 00000000000284a3  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so (__glGetDrawable+338)
  #13  pc 0000000000029cfb  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
  #14  pc 00000000000083a9  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so (_ApiMakeCurrent+32)
  #15  pc 0000000000009987  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so (veglMakeCurrent+1838)
  #16  pc 0000000000009dcb  /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so (eglMakeCurrent+54)
  #17  pc 000000000000d459  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::egl_display_t::makeCurrent(android::egl_context_t*, android::egl_context_t*, void*, void*, void*, void*, void*, void*)+84)
  #18  pc 000000000000fbc5  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglMakeCurrent+240)
  #19  pc 0000000000073569  /data/data/net.my.app/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so
```

Is it possible to handle the situation when the app runs out of memory somehow and close the app gracefully showing a message to the user, for example? And does it make a sense (it is not clear whether crash rate affects app rating in Google Play or not)?

Comment: You'll need to allocate your own memory up front and manage what memory you use. If you use the default heap, and you run out of memory, there's not much you can do.

Comment: I need some callback in C++ runtime lib in this case, because 'malloc' can be called by OpenGL (as in the above stack trace) or by QT internally. In other words, I need to control where 'malloc' gets the memory. Or at least been notified when 'malloc' cannot allocate the memory.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It seems like a really roundabout way to solve an underlying problem. You can hook into malloc and figure out when memory will run out before the next memory allocation, but this seems really fragile. Check out [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md) documentation for advanced `malloc` debugging.

Comment: I can easily manage memory I use in my C++ code by using custom std::allocator that will work with a big pre-allocated memory block, but I do not know how to do this with OpenGL and QT internal code that calls 'malloc'. I wander if there is a way to use custom allocator with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

On the Java side you can get the memory size with this, with API 16 or newer:

```
        ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
        long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This a useful information, but it is not clear how much memory I need to make OpenGL context current, for example (see the above stack trace)... but theoretically there can be an estimation.

Comment: as far as I see from docs analyzing 'availMem' is even better than 'totalMem', so should I write something like 'if (availMem < N) showMessageAndExit()'? At least this code does not look very smart :) Probably I am looking for more advanced mechanisms.